# How do I correct my arrays to create my desired table output?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, one for creating the first column (service) in a table like structure and the second for every other column (day) after that. First column array has the structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DPW
    [1] => PNS
    [2] => WS1
    [3] => WS2
)
```

This is a dynamic array so there could be more values than this, but it will always be unique and sorted alphabetically.

My second array for the other columns has the structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 42016
                            [message] => 07:00 START
                            [service] => DPW

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 42016
                            [message] => 16:30 START
                            [service] => PNS
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 42016
                            [message] => 
                            [service] => WS1
                        )

    // etc ...


    [3] => Array
        (
            [Thursday] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 42017
                            [message] =>
                            [service] => DPW
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 42017
                            [message] => 16:00 CUT OFF
                            [service] => DPW
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 42017
                            [message] =>
                            [service] => PNS
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

So basically each day is the next column. My problem is I initially thought that the service key in the second array was always in the same order for each day, but its not. You can see from the Thursday that DPW is twice in a row, whereas Monday isn't. I can change the format of these arrays, so this is where my questions lie.

[View desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KowNI.jpg)

My thoughts are for starters the day should contain the same number of keys as the services array, so should I add a blank value to make up the same number of keys? To cater for the same service in a row should I add a further level to cater for multiple values look like so:

```
Array
(

    // etc ...


    [3] => Array
        (
            [Thursday] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [date] => 42017
                                    [message] =>
                                    [service] => DPW
                                 )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [date] => 42017
                                    [message] =>
                                    [service] => DPW
                                 )
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [date] => 42017
                                    [message] =>
                                    [service] => PNS
                                 )
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (

                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I have also added in the blank values. Finally how would I print these values in the same order as the first (services) array so they aren't under the wrong service?

If is difficult to explain this and I could be going about it the wrong way, but that's why I am asking the questions.

**EDIT:**

Almost there with this, my only issue now is I need to show the Start and Cut Off date as being the same item spread out across multiple days. For instance the array might have these values at some point:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 42016
        [message] => 16:30 START
        [service] => DPM
    )

// etc...

[3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 42021
        [message] => 16:30 CUT OFF
        [service] => DPM
    )
```

So I need a way to have these on their own row with a background colour or something to show they are the one item, like the graphic above. Not sure if this is possible?

Thanks
Robert!

Comment: *"How do I create a"* - keep going... (not much of an attention grabber).

Comment: @Fred -ii- Clearly a mistake in the title name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but it might help :

```
$services = array('DPW', 'PNS', 'WS1', 'WS2');
$days = array(
    array(
        'Monday' => array(
                    array(
                            'date' => 42016,
                            'message' => '07:00 START',
                            'service' => 'DPW'

                        ),
                    array(
                            'date' => 42016,
                            'message' => '16:30 START',
                            'service' => 'PNS'
                        ),
                    array(
                            'date' => 42016,
                            'message' => '',
                            'service' => 'WS1'
                        ),
                ),
    ),

    array(
            'Thursday' => array(
                    array(
                            'date' => 42017,
                            'message' => '',
                            'service' => 'DPW'
                        ),
                    array(
                            'date' => 42017,
                            'message' => '16:00 CUT OFF',
                            'service' => 'DPW'
                        ),
                    array(
                            'date' => 42017,
                            'message' => '',
                            'service' => 'PNS'
                        )
                )
        )
    );
```

And here is the HTML Table:

```
<?php $service_days = []; ?>
<table cellpadding="10" width="100%" align="left">
    <thead>
        <td style="background:#333;color:#FFF">Service</td>
        <?php foreach($days as $day): ?>
            <td style="background:#666;color:#FFF"><?php echo array_keys($day)[0]; ?></td>
            <?php 
              foreach(array_values($day)[0] as $d)  
                   $service_days[array_keys($day)[0]][$d['service']][] = $d;
           ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </thead>

    <?php foreach($services as $service):  ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $service ?></td>     

            <?php foreach($service_days as $day => $srv): ?>
                <td>    
                <?php foreach($srv as $_service => $periode): ?>

                    <?php if($_service == $service): ?>

                            <?php foreach($periode as $p): ?>
                                <p style="background:#DDD"><?php echo $p['date'], '<br>', $p['message']; ?></p>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
                &nbsp;</td> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks your example has been a great help, much simpler way to display the table than I was trying. My only other issue now is how do I show the start and finish I have edited my original question so you can see my problem.

Comment: I tought you might have the 'CUT OFF' on a different day, not the same day with different date

Comment: Yeah it will be difficult. Need to relate each item somehow.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, for exp you have `$array['Thursday'][0]['date']=42017` and `$array['Thursday'][1]['date']=42017` for the same day, so how can you tell the start date is for `Monday` or `Tuesday` ?

Comment: I think that number is wrong, waiting for feedback on it, I think it should be a date, or should I say needs to be a date. Basically this information is being parsed from an XML file and then turned into the schedule table.

Comment: Even so, you can't tell in which day the CUT OFF date must be displayed, that's the problem.

Comment: I think if maybe the CUT OFF date was included with the day service array, that could be a solution. So basically along with the start date there would be another key for the end date.

Comment: JC Sama I have eventually got feedback on this. I have had the feed modified to include the cut Off date in each service item. So basically for item we now know the cut off date.

Comment: can you post the whole array ( new one )